# unable to cancel a stripe billing subscription using php

Tags: php, stripe-payments

i am trying to cancel a subscription i have made via stripe api.

i am following the example code snippet from the developer docs at

https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/canceling-pausing

so this what i have done

```
<?php
require_once('str/init.php');

// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// i have used my demo keys here
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("stripe demo key was used");

// i have picked a test subscription i made on my dashboard on stripe and put its id here
$subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::retrieve('sub id');


$subscription->cancel();

?>
```

my expectation was that wen i ran that code the status of the of subscription would change from "active" to "cancelled" or watever term is used

Please help

Comment: Your code is identical to the example in the doc, so it should work. Stripe has excellent tech support, maybe you should ask them.

Comment: You can also look at the logs in the Stripe Dashboard to see if there was any error.

Comment: ok thanks, it returned a 200 status (which means it went on well(, so why didnt it update the subscription to cancelled, u av any idea

Comment: No idea. We use Stripe, but we don't use subscriptions.

Comment: update my bad, it worked correctly i had to sort the table properly to see it